# Как получить значение из класса

Tags: javascript

```
function getCard(object) {
  const сardGet = document.getElementById('template-card');
  const сardPast = сardGet.content.cloneNode(true);
  сardPast.querySelector('.card__image').setAttribute('style', `background-image: url(${object.link})`);
  return сardPast;
};
```

Есть функция, которая копирует блок и в нем в диве=card__image устанавливает значение бэграунду. . А как можно получить это значение и передать его уже в html тегу img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style.backgroundImage` возвращает строку-фоновую картинку, но только если она добавлена непосредственно в HTML, в атрибут style (в том числе и через JS). Если картинку добавили через внешний CSS - вернет пустую строку. Поэтому для более надежного результата нужно добавить `getComputedStyle(elem).backgroundImage`

```js
let moo = document.querySelector('.moo');
let boo = document.querySelector('.boo');

console.log( getBgImage(moo) );
console.log( getBgImage(boo) );
console.log( getBgImage( document.body ) );


function getBgImage(node) {
  let bg = node.style.backgroundImage || getComputedStyle(node).backgroundImage;
  
  return bg.replace(/url\(['"]?|['"]?\)/ig, "");
}
```

```css
.moo {
  background-image: url('moo.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="moo"></div>
<div class="boo" style="background-image: url('boo.png')"></div>
```

`['"]?` — Одиночная или двойная кавычка, `?` означает "может быть, может не быть"

https://learn.javascript.ru/ >> "Регулярные выражениия" (часть 3, пункт 7)

---

setAttribute можете заменить на

```
сardPast.querySelector('.card__image').style.backgroundImage = `url(${object.link})`
```

---

P.s. Можно сделать более общую функцию:

```js
let moo = document.querySelector('.moo');
let boo = document.querySelector('.boo');

console.log( getStyle(moo, 'backgroundImage') );
console.log( getStyle(moo, 'color') );
console.log( getStyle(boo, 'backgroundImage') );

function getStyle(node, prop) {
  return node.style[prop] || getComputedStyle(node)[prop];
}
```

```css
.moo {
  background-image: url('moo.png');
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="moo"></div>
<div class="boo" style="background-image: url('boo.png')"></div>
```

Просят стили: Дает стили. Дальнейшее преобразование строки не её забота.

Comment: смотрите, может я не понял чего. у меня изначально у блока нету bg image. я устанавливаю ему фон - беру ссылку на фон(фотку) из массива. так вот я хочу понять, как мне получить теперь этот bg и его значение установить уже в html тегу img

Comment: регулярки пока мне рановато)

Comment: или может я не о том думаю. в общем у меня есть блоки с фотками, добвляются фотки туда бэграундом. и есть блок , который открывается при нажатии на любой блок с фотками. я не могу сообразить, как из блока с фотками брать значение и передавать на новый блок

Comment: @newStudent Ну при клике на блок, вы же можете через querySelector достать тот блок, у кого добавлен bg-image ? Или текущий блок, через `this`. Соответственно останется дописать `img.src = getBgImage(elem);` пример: https://jsfiddle.net/nd6gowym/1/

Comment: спасибо большое